# React Redux Websocket Message Reducer State Shaping

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux

I'm creating a React Redux(Thunk) application that is populated via a single websocket to a server.

I get data from the server by subscribing to different 'processes', and the data for each process is returned as an Object eg:

```
subscribe:process1,process2,process3
```

This will return 3 messages in the following format:

```
{process1: {key: value, key: value}} etc.
```

I'm currently using [redux-websocket](https://github.com/giantmachines/redux-websocket) middleware which fires an action on each message:

```
{
  type: WEBSOCKET:MESSAGE,
  payload: {
    timestamp: Date,
    event: Event,
    data: string
  }
}
```

I then have a reducer to populate the state tree with the data that I need.

This works fine, but my state tree gets quite deeply nested:

```
{messageReducer: {
    process1 : {
        key: value
    },
    process2 : {
        key: value
    },
    etc...
    }
}}
```

Each process can return several hundreds of items, some are objects/arrays.
Whats the best way of handling this?

Is it OK to continue as I am, or should I promote each process to the top level of the state tree? If so, how do I get this outside of messageReducer?